# how to generate a php image for src

Tags: php, image

I would like to use:

```
src="my_generated_image_from_php.jpg"
```

instead of

`src="my_php_image.php"`

How do I do it?

my_php_image.php like:

```
<?php
     ......
     Header('Content-type: image/png');
     imagepng($im2);
     imagedestroy($im2);
     ......     
?>
```

Comment: Put them in the same directory?

Comment: Do you mean how do you get a php file to show up as .jpg?  You would have to use mod_rewrite

Answer (score 1):

You are probably thinking about URL rewriting (`mod_rewrite`), which is used to serve something with different URL.

`my_generated_image_from_php.jpeg` (hiding real extension of the file called - 'php') may then get you the same thing as `my_php_image.php?image=my_generated_image_from_php.jpeg`.

When it comes to MIME-type and header of the script's response, it would be good if you could include it, but this is not required to achieve what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to send an image header along with the image binary in your my_php_image.php file like so:

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo file_get_contents("my_generated_image_from_php.jpeg");
```

Obviously, you'll need to make sure the relative path of the image is correct for it to work. Otherwise, just use an absolute path from the root directory.

If you do this, you'll be able to use the second option as the image source.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how Drupal does it.  Your URL to the image looks like `index.php?q=some/path/to/the/image.jpg` but if your webserver is set up right these simple rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Now PHP can extract the request path with

```
$request_path = strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?')
$base_path_len = strlen(rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '\/'));
// Unescape and strip $base_path prefix, leaving q without a leading slash.
$path = substr(urldecode($request_path), $base_path_len + 1);
```

Once you have done this as BraedenP says you just need the correct HTTP headers and off you go.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you will need to save your php generated image as an actual image file. I would start reading here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php